# Advantages of UDP over TCP?

Tags: tcp, udp

TCP has a greater computation overhead to ensure reliable delivery of packets. But, since modern networks are fast, is there any scenario in which *performance of UDP outweighs the reliability of TCP?*

Is there any other particular advantage of UDP over TCP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is it appropriate to use UDP instead of TCP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099672/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-udp-instead-of-tcp)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can see two cases, where UDP would have an upper hand over TCP.

First, one of the attractive features of UDP is that since it does not need to retransmit lost packets nor does it do any connection setup, sending data incurs less delay. This lower delay makes UDP an appealing choice for delay-sensitive applications like audio and video.

Second, multicast applications are built on top of UDP since they have to do point to multipoint. Using TCP for multicast applications would be hard since now the sender would have to keep track of retransmissions/sending rate for multiple receivers.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your usage. If your application is time sensitive, like Voice over IP, then you don't care about missing packets. What you care about is the delay in that case.

You should have a look at this answer: [What are examples of TCP and UDP in real life?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330277/what-is-the-example-of-tcp-and-udp-in-real-life)

You could also look at the Wikipedia related section: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Comparison_of_UDP_and_TCP

Answer (score 3):

udp provides better application level control over what data is sent....since the data is packaged in a udp segment and immediately passed over to the network layer......hence no-frills segment delivery service is observed.

There is no need for connection establishment hence no delay(unlike tcp...which requires handshaking before the actual data transfer)

There is no need to maintain connection state in the end systems(ie no need for send and receive buffers,congestion control parameters and sequence and acknowledgement number parameters)..hence more active clients could be supported

Small packet header overhead for udp(only 8 bytes) where as tcp has 20 bytes of header

Answer (score 3):

Facebook uses UDP connections instead of TCP/IP to connect to theirs Memcached Servers

Answer (score 2):

Applications that require constant data flow, bulk data and which require fastness than reliability uses UDP over TCP.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of differences of UDP over TCP.

First, TCP is connection-based whereas UDP is connectionless.

- Connection-based: Make sure that all messages will arrive and arrive in the correct order.
- Connectionless: It does not guarantee order or completeness.

Second, Here is why UDP is faster over TCP:

- UDP does not require ACK message back
- UDP has no flow control
- No duplication verification at the receiving end
- Shorter header